# Objects appear as outline only

Tags: eevee-render-engine, gpu

I need your help Blender suddenly became like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an AMD Gpu? There have been many posts recently about how updating it has caused these problems with OpenCl or something like that.

Comment: Revert your drivers to the previous version and it should be fixed.

Comment: yes I do have, do you think it has something to do with the Radeon software?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/khzhcc/meta_attention_to_all_amd_gpu_owners/

Found it

Comment: thank you for this, Im gonna check it out

Comment: Hey guys ! thank you for your help ! It's now fixed ( I think ) I did not revert the driver version , but I follow the alternative method in which I have to turn on the high quality performance in the Render Properties tab

Comment: ok thanks for this update! interesting to know an alternative

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that works for me !

Enabling High Quality Normals in Performance under the Render tab.

Thank you again!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good luck on your final